# GoogleApiClientのLocationServicesAPIとActivityRecognitionAPIの同時使用は可能なのでしょうか？

Tags: android, java, android-studio, google-api

Android StudioでGoogleApiClientのLocationServicesAPIとActivityRecognitionAPI を使い、
人が歩いているのか止まっているのかを判別し、その結果とその人の現在地をGoogleMap上に表示するというアプリの開発をしています。
LocationServicesAPIを使用して、現在地の位置情報の取得しMap上に表示するプログラミングは参考書やサイトを見ながら完成させました。
続いて参考になるサイトや参考書を見ながら、ActivityRecognitionAPIを使い開発を進めているときに、
GoogleApiClientは異なった2つのAPIを同時に使用できるのかと疑問に思い質問さしていただきました。
GoogleApiClientのインスタンスは2つ作成可能なのでしょうか？
また2つのAPIは同時に使用できるのでしょうか？